# Open source ASP.NET Gantt Chart Web Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-applications, open-source

Does anyone know where I can get a Open source ASP.NET Gantt Chart / Web Control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [Silverlight Gantt Chart](http://silverlightgantt.codeplex.com/) library from CodePlex.

Answer (score 2):

You may use dhtmlxGantt, an open source (GPL) JavaScript Gantt chart, with ASP.NET. Here is the tutorial on how to use it with ASP.NET MVC: http://www.dhtmlx.com/blog/using-dhtmlx-gantt-chart-asp-net-mvc/

(Disclosure - I work at DHTMLX)

Answer (score 1):

This is not ASP.NET nor open source but still might interest you, the Ext Gantt. Built using just HTML/CSS/JS and very interactive:

http://ext-scheduler.com/gantt.html

Comment: Your affiliation to the company that sells Ext Scheduler should be disclosed in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this one, seems to be quite simple to implement http://www.naspinski.net/post/Simple-Gantt-Chart-with-Aspnet.aspx

Comment: This link is no longer accessible.