# Gantt chart asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, gantt-chart

Does some one know of a free Gantt Chart control? If yes, can you please share the information about this control with me? am working in ASP.NET 4.0 based application.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2136429/562769

Answer (score 2):

Try look here:

[Open source ASP.NET Gantt Chart Web Control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2136429/735864)

Comment: thanks danyolgiax.have you tried any of those, which one is better ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Fusion Charts and they are good.

They have a free version > http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/gallery/

Comment: fusion chart is flash based . i want one which works with javascript

Comment: fusion charts work with javascript. you provide the the data in xml format using javascript and then it generates the flash chart. ofcourse it won't work if your clients don't support flash.